# google recaptcha

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

Alguien me puede ayudar, quiero realizar un google reCAPTCHA en modo local host con base de datos XAMPP, pero a la hora de realizarlo me muestra este error en la página web.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dentro de la página de [re captcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/) debes encontrar dentro de tus propiedades el símbolo de engrane (parte superior derecha como muestro en imagen)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez dentro, asegúrate que en el área de `dominios` esté agregado `localhost`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta manera ya podrás usarlo en localhost:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: me fue perfecto, muchas gracias =)

Comment: qué bueno saberlo, si te sirvió la respuesta, márcala como respuesta aceptada para que otros puedan encontrar la misma solución más rápido